# Не работают cogs в связке с PyQt5+Discord.py

Tags: python, pyqt5, discord.py

Простенький бот для discord, единственная его функция приветствовать зашедших в голосовой канал пользователей. Без использования PyQt5, бот работает без ошибок и как положено.
После того как прикрутил интерфейс, он всё так же запускается с помощью button, но функция приветствия перестает реагировать. Как я понимаю проблема с отправкой сигнала из дискорда, но куда двигаться дальше не пойму.

**main.py**

```
import os
import sys
import json
import asyncio
import discord

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from discord.ext import commands
from asyncqt import QEventLoop, asyncSlot

import botDesign

with open('./master.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

TOKEN = data["guild"]["TOKEN"]
BP = data["guild"]["command_prefix"]

intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=BP, case_insensitive=True, intents=intents)
bot.remove_command('help')


class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, botDesign.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.client = MyDiscordCLient()
        self.pushBotButton.clicked.connect(self.on_connect_bot)
        self.pushCogsButton.clicked.connect(self.load_cog)

    @asyncSlot()
    async def on_connect_bot(self):
        await self.client.start(TOKEN)

    @asyncSlot()
    async def load_cog(self):
        for filename in os.listdir("./cogs"):
            if filename.endswith(".py") and not filename.startswith("_"):
                bot.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}")
                print(f'Loaded {filename[:-3]}')


class MyDiscordCLient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Bot logged discord server.')
        await self.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.Game('test'))


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    loop = QEventLoop(app)
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    loop.run_forever()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**файл в /cogs**

```
import discord
import audiopath
import audioread
from discord.ext import commands
from time import sleep


class Audio(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_voice_state_update(self, member: discord.Member, before, after):

        vc_before = before.channel
        vc_after = after.channel
        if vc_before == vc_after:
            return
        if vc_before is None and vc_after is not None:
            channel = member.voice.channel
            vc = await channel.connect()
            sleep(.1)
            vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(audiopath.connect))
            with audioread.audio_open(audiopath.connect) as f:
                #   Start Playing
                sleep(f.duration)
            await vc.disconnect()

        elif vc_after is None and vc_before is not None:
            return
        else:
            channel = member.voice.channel
            vc = await channel.connect()
            sleep(.1)
            vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(audiopath.connect))
            with audioread.audio_open(audiopath.connect) as f:
                #   Start Playing
                sleep(f.duration)
            await vc.disconnect()


def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Audio(bot))
```

Comment: Попробуйте разделить задания на патоки с помощью библиотеки Threads

Comment: Спасибо, я попробовал, но видимо мне не хватает опыта. По прежнему не смог добиться рабочего состояния . Буду пыхтеть дальше)